# How to show particular labels post in Drop down list on blogger?

Tags: web, blogger

I want to show particular labels post in drop down list for each post.it can be as below photo or show just only specific label for that post.

[image: drop down list example]

Comment: Please explain your problem add some codes or links to help us solve your problem [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: obsesskpop.blogspot.com this is my blogger link. i want to display dropdown label list just like the above picture in every each post on my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code display post labels in dropdown list. Put it after `<data:post.body/>` tag

```
<b:if cond='data:top.showPostLabels and data:post.labels'>
    <select>
        <option value='select'><data:postLabelsLabel/></option>
        <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
            <option expr:href='data:label.url'><data:label.name/></option>
        </b:loop>
    </select>
</b:if>
```

You can show or hide the list and change the default selected name from your blog posts gadget. Go to **Layout** > **Blog Posts** > **Edit**

[image]

But unfortunately you can't get posts number inside blog posts widget as in labels widget.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bassam. but how can i can the default name which is Labels: to sth else? also adding number of that label posts

Comment: If the answer is helpful, mark it to help other users.